# JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' parse - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

> "JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token'<'"

Error is showing while hitting the *API*. (Response is in the *JSON* format.) I'm trying to build a login form but I cannot retrieve user data from my database server.

```
constructor(){
super()
    this.state={
         email:'',
         password:'',
    }
}
handleLoginUser(){
            fetch('https://"mygoogleclouddatabaseip"/users/login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                      Accept: 'application/json',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(this.state)})
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        return response.json();})
                    .then(responseData => {
                         console.log(responseData);
                         let result = JSON.parse(responseData);
                         return result;})
                    .then(data => {
                        if (result.success){
                            alert("Login successful");
                        }
                        else
                            alert("Unable to Login");
                    })
               }
}
```

Comment: Check the response from the server. It sounds like the server may be returning HTML or some other non-JSON response.

Comment: "Response is in the JSON format" — Maybe it should be, but the error message says otherwise.

Comment: `response.json()` **and** `let result = JSON.parse(responseData);`? Really? Are you sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `response` isn't a valid json and it gives you the error when trying to do `response.json()`.

Please debug it and to handle the case where `response` isn't a valid json.

Or the other problem can be here

```
let result = JSON.parse(responseData);
```

If `responseData` is already a javascript object, using `JSON.parse` will give you an error and if `response.json()` worked, it means that `JSON.parse` isn't necessary and is giving you the error.

You might ask

> Why `JSON.parse` isn't necessary?

Because `response.json()` transforms the response to a javascript object and `JSON.parse` also do that.

The correct way is to use `response.json()` and not `JSON.parse` (only if the response is a valid json).

Comment: I did your recommendation but now it gives "network request failed" error